# Utilizando o comando Case When Then com Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho a seguinte estrutura correspondente a uma tabela no meu Banco de Dados:

```
Cat_Codigo, 
Cat_Descricao, 
Cat_Observacao, 
Cat_Status
```

Onde o `Cat_Status` é definido por 0 ou 1, sendo 0 -> Desativo e 1 -> Ativo.

Porém não quero exibir para o usuario final, 0 ou 1, mas sim Destivo e Ativo, eu sei que isso é possivel de se realizar atraves do seguinte comando SQL

```
SELECT  cat_codigo As Codigo,  cat_descricao As Descricao, cat_observacao AS Observacao, 
CASE cat_status WHEN '1' THEN 'Ativo' WHEN '0' THEN 'Desativo' END AS Status FROM Categoria
```

Utilizando o comando `CASE` consigo definir isso.

Agora como faço a mesma coisa atraves do Entity Framework? Qual método posso utilizar para alterar os campos para um nome. 
Na minha classe o atributo status está como `int`, isso ocasionaria algum problema também?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples, é criar um atributo apenas com `get`. Ele não será armazenado no banco dados, e deve te atender. Além disso, é reutilizável.

```
public class Categoria 
{
    public int Cat_Codigo  { get; set; }
    public string Cat_Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Cat_Observacao { get; set; }
    public int Cat_Status { get; set; }

    // c# 6
    public string DescricaoStatus => Cat_Status == 1 ? "Ativo" : "Inativo";
}
```

ou

```
public string DescricaoStatus 
{
  get 
  {
    return Cat_Status == 1 ? "Ativo" : "Inativo";
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver meu problema com sua informação. bom, tenho outra duvida relacionada ao entity framework, posso realizar uma pergunta a você por aqui ou devo criar um novo topico?

Comment: Dá uma pesquisada nas perguntas existentes. Se nao achar a resposta você pode fazer uma nova pergunta(tópico). O termo correto aqui é pergunta pois não é fórum.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade seria você utilizar o operador condicional [`?:`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ty67wk28.aspx) retorna um de dois valores, dependendo do valor de uma expressão booleana.

```
var categorias = context.Categoria.
        Select(a => new {
            Codigo = a.Cat_Codigo,
            Descricao = a.Cat_Descricao,
            Observacao = a.Cat_Observacao,
            Status = a.Cat_status == 0 ? "Ativo" : "Desativo"
        });
```

Comment: No caso quando eu faço Status = a.Cat_status == 0 ? "Ativo" : "Desativo" e meu atributo Status é um integer não ocorre problemas? no caso eu não atribuiria o valor Ativo ou Desativo para a variavel Status?

Comment: Nesse exemplo que lhe mostrei o Status vai ser uma string, pois estou retornando um tipo anonimo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo que você crie um objeto do tipo DaoRetorno com os campos iguais do Banco só que com um atributo de string para poder atribuir o valor depois de listar, no caso um statusstr (str de string).

Crie uma lista do tipo DaoRetorno.

```
List<DaoRetorno> lista = conexao.Categoria.Select(x=> new DaoRetorno () { codigo = x.codigo, descricao = x.descricao, obs= x.obs, status=x.status }).toList();

foreach (item i in lista)
{
  if (i.status = 1){
       i.statusstr = 'Ativo';
  }
  else
  {
       i.statusstr = 'Desativo';
  }
}
```

Ou seja passa um por um e atribui o valor na lista, depois disso sua lista vai ter o campo preenchido, só usar o valor depois.